# how to convert MessageResponse type to ResponseEntity<?> return type

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Service Class which has following method

**NewCartService.java:**

```
@Service
public class NewCartService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CartRepository cartRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CartDao cartDao;
    @Autowired
    private Mailer mailService;

    public MessageResponse order(List<Cart> cart) throws MessagingException {

        for (Cart cart1 : cart) {
            String userName = cart1.getUserName();
            String password = cart1.getPassword();
            String productName = cart1.getProductName();
            String price = cart1.getPrice();
            String discription = cart1.getDiscription();

            if (!cartRepository.existsAllByUserNameAndPasswordAndProductNameAndPriceAndDiscription(userName, password, productName, price, discription)) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("not found");
            }
            MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
            Mustache m = mf.compile("cart.mustache");

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            String messageText = "";

            List<Cart> carts = cartDao.getCart(cart);

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("carts", carts);
            Writer m1 = m.execute(writer, params);
            System.out.println(m1);
            messageText = m1.toString();

            mailService.sendMail("/*email address*/", "/*email address*/", messageText, "demo", true);
            cartRepository.deleteByUserNameAndPasswordAndProductNameAndPriceAndDiscription(userName, password, productName, price, discription);

            return new MessageResponse("product Successfully ordered from cart");
        }
        throw new BadArgumentsException("bad arguments");
    }

}
```

I have controller

**CartController.java:**

```
@RestController
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    public CartService cartService;

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<?> orders(@Valid @RequestBody List<Cart> carts) throws MessagingException {
        return newCartService.order(carts);// it gives error because i need to convert MessageResponse into the ResponseEntity<?>
    }
}
```

Now my Question is that how can i convert these MessageResponse into the ResponseEntity<?> ?

please suggest me code so that i can solve these issue and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does your API specification want GET /orders to return? What is the MessageResponse class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```java
return new ResponseEntity<>(newCartService.order(carts), HttpStatus.OK);
```

or as suggested in the comments:

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok(newCartService.order(carts));
```

Comment: more modern writing: ResponseEntity<>.ok(...)

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you want set header with response entity you can try:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Custom-Header", "<header>");
        
return new ResponseEntity<>(newCartService.order(carts), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

alternative you can use:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header("Custom-Header", "<header>")
        .body(newCartService.order(carts));
```